# Catching an out of range exception for a particular variable in C#

Tags: c#, variables, outofrangeexception

In the code below I read through a smartsheet from column to column running some code until it throws an outofrange exception whereby I make the cellNumber = 0, and increase the row number (in other words move to a new line).

```
while (rowNumber < totalRows)
{
   try
   {
        do code....
        cellNumber++
   } catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
   {
   cellNumber = 0;
   rowNumber++;
   }
}
```

Is there anyway to only catch the out of range exception associated with cellNumber?

Comment: Catching exceptions like `ArgumentException`, `NotSupportedException`, `NotImplementedException` is generally a bad idea in my mind, it would be better to avoid them from happening in the first place.

Comment: I don't know anything about Smartsheet, but surely it provides some method you can call to determine the number of cells in the row in question? Then use that to control a nested loop, like @ragtimewilly is suggesting.

Comment: It does but I am using a Json file retrieved from smartsheets

Comment: Matthew your absolutly right. It was my first time working with a json format and I should have just used a count. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing something along these lines:

```
 foreach (Row row in sheet.Rows)
 {
     foreach (Cell c in row.Cells)
     {
         //  do code....
     }
 }
```